# Is there a term for someone who barely moves their arms whilst walking?

Tags: terminology, slang, nicknames

I know someone who barely moves his arms when he walks, a bit like Frankenstein's monster.

There is a Seinfeld episode ("[The Summer of George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Summer_of_George)") in which someone with the same behaviour is made fun of by Elaine who describes it as if "she's carrying invisible suitcases".

Is there a term for people like that?

Comment: For Frank's monster I would say "stiffly".

Comment: Or perhaps "like a zombie".

Answer (score 4):

This question brought to mind a toy we had when I was a kid. It was made popular on the TV show "Romper Room" Plastic cylinders (like small coffee cans) with loops of cord attached - and you'd stand on them, hold the cords taut, and clomp around with your arms at your sides.

If you called this person a ***Romper Stomper*** I'm pretty sure folks of my generation would understand. (Sorry about you young'uns - you have so few amusements that don't involve electronics) (US)

Comment: Ah! Australian skinheads. I get it.

Comment: Sorry Ricky, I forgot about the rest of the English-speaking planet. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

He is perhaps walking **with dangling arms**.

[image]

> I like to believe that Junho really does harbor otherworldly hypnotic
>   power over the 2PM boys and can "conduct" them in their zombie form at
>   his free will, to cater to his every whim with their limp dangling
>   arms and stumbling zombie feet.

Comment: Looks like zombies dancing their version of "Gangam style"!